# Optimal way to ignore duplicate inserts?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, insert, unique-constraint, duplication

## Background

This problem relates to ignoring duplicate inserts using PostgreSQL 9.2 or greater. The reason I ask is because of this code:

```
  -- Ignores duplicates.
  INSERT INTO
    db_table (tbl_column_1, tbl_column_2)
  VALUES (
    SELECT
      unnseted_column,
      param_association
    FROM
      unnest( param_array_ids ) AS unnested_column
  );
```

The code is unencumbered by checks for existing values. (In this particular situation, the user does not care about errors from inserting duplicates -- the insertion should "just work".) Adding code in this situation to explicitly test for duplicates imparts complications.

## Problem

In PostgreSQL, I have found a few ways to ignore duplicate inserts.

### Ignore Duplicates #1

Create a transaction that catches unique constraint violations, taking no action:

```
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO db_table (tbl_column) VALUES (v_tbl_column);
  EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    -- Ignore duplicate inserts.
  END;
```

### Ignore Duplicates #2

Create a rule to ignore duplicates on a given table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE db_table_ignore_duplicate_inserts AS
    ON INSERT TO db_table
   WHERE (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM db_table
          WHERE db_table.tbl_column = NEW.tbl_column)) DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

## Questions

My questions are mostly academic:

- What method is most efficient?
- What method is most maintainable, and why?
- What is the standard way to ignore insert duplication errors with PostgreSQL?
- Is there a technically more efficient way to ignore duplicate inserts; if so, what is it?

Thank you!

Comment: I think not trying to insert duplicates at all is the best solution to your problem.  Check for existence of the given key value like `INSERT ... SELECT /* not VALUES! */ ... WHERE ...`

Comment: Your first INSERT statement does not check for anything (and besides the syntax isn't correct either)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the answers on the other question (of which this one is considered a duplicate) mention, there is (since version 9.5) a native [`UPSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) functionality.  For older versions, keep reading :)

I have set up a test for checking the options.  I'll include the code below, which can be run in `psql` on a linux/Unix box (simply because for the sake of clarity in the results, I piped the output of the setup commands to `/dev/null` - on a Windows box one could choose a log file instead).

I tried to make different results comparable by using more than one (that is, 100) `INSERT` per type, run from a loop inside a `plpgsql` stored procedure.  Additionally, before each run, the table is reset by truncating and reinserting the original data.

Checking a few test runs, it looks like that using the rule and explicitly adding `WHERE NOT EXISTS` ot the `INSERT` statement spend similar time, while cathcing an exception takes significantlly more time to complete.

The latter isn't that [surprising](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING):

> Tip: A block containing an EXCEPTION clause is significantly more
>   expensive to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore, don't
>   use EXCEPTION without need.

Personally, because of readability and maintainability, I prefer adding the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` bit to the `INSERT`s themselves.  Just like with triggers (which could be tested here as well), debugging (or simply tracing `INSERT` behaviour) is more complicated with rules present.

And the code I used (feel free to point misconceptions or other problems):

```
\o /dev/null
\timing off

-- set up data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS insert_test;

CREATE TABLE insert_test_base_data (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 double precision,
    col2 text
);

CREATE TABLE insert_test (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 double precision,
    col2 text
);

INSERT INTO insert_test_base_data
SELECT i, (SELECT random() AS r WHERE s.i = s.i)
FROM 
    generate_series(2, 200, 2) s(i)
;

UPDATE insert_test_base_data
SET col2 = md5(col1::text)
;

INSERT INTO insert_test
SELECT *
FROM insert_test_base_data
;



-- function with exception block to be called later
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_test_insert(
    id integer,
    col1 double precision,
    col2 text
)
RETURNS void AS
$body$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO insert_test
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
    ;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN unique_violation
    THEN NULL;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;



-- function running plain SQL ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_test_where_not_exists()
RETURNS void AS
$body$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. 100
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO insert_test
        SELECT i, rnd, md5(rnd::text)
        FROM (SELECT random() AS rnd) r
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM insert_test
            WHERE id = i
        )
        ;
    END LOOP;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;



-- call a function with exception block
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_test_function_with_exception_block()
RETURNS void AS
$body$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. 100
    LOOP
        PERFORM f_insert_test_insert(i, rnd, md5(rnd::text))
        FROM (SELECT random() AS rnd) r
        ;
    END LOOP;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;



-- leave checking existence to a rule
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_test_rule()
RETURNS void AS
$body$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. 100
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO insert_test
        SELECT i, rnd, md5(rnd::text)
        FROM (SELECT random() AS rnd) r
        ;
    END LOOP;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;



\o
\timing on


\echo 
\echo 'check before INSERT'

SELECT insert_test_where_not_exists();

\echo 



\o /dev/null

\timing off

TRUNCATE insert_test;

INSERT INTO insert_test
SELECT *
FROM insert_test_base_data
;

\timing on

\o

\echo 'catch unique-violation'

SELECT insert_test_function_with_exception_block();

\echo 
\echo 'implementing a RULE'

\o /dev/null
\timing off

TRUNCATE insert_test;

INSERT INTO insert_test
SELECT *
FROM insert_test_base_data
;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE db_table_ignore_duplicate_inserts AS
    ON INSERT TO insert_test
    WHERE EXISTS ( 
        SELECT 1
        FROM insert_test
        WHERE id = NEW.id
    ) 
    DO INSTEAD NOTHING;

\o 
\timing on

SELECT insert_test_rule();
```

Comment: Thank you for this. My only issue with adding `EXISTS` to each `INSERT` statement is that it can lead to duplicated code. I use a single stored procedure to wrap the `INSERT` statement, but I can imagine scenarios where multiple `INSERT` statements and hence multiple checks are present in the code base.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: when it comes to data validation, duplication and redundancy aren't (necessarily) bad things

Comment: @DaveJarvis If you centralize your INSERT into a stored procedure, then you are fine.  If you don't, you repeat your INSERT with or without the existence check...