# How do I in "Navicat for PostgreSQL" run a simple PL/pgSQL script like I would in MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, navicat

I don't want a function or anything. I just want to run/test a simple script with some PL/pgSQL features in it. Something like the following:

```
IF 1=1 THEN
    SELECT concat('Hello', 'World');
END IF;
```

I'm sure the syntax is correct, but it doesn't work in the normal "Query Editor" like I'd do it in Microsoft SQL Server. I get the following error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: IF 1=1 THEN
        ^
```

I'm running Navicat for PostgreSQL version 11.1.13 (64-bit) on a Windows 10 machine. `select version()` says the following:

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
```

**edit:**

I just realized that this question might be the victim of the X-Y Problem. What I really want to do is to test the following way of inserting values ignoring duplicates:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO db_table (tbl_column) VALUES (v_tbl_column);
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    -- Ignore duplicate inserts.
END;
```

I found it here: [Optimal way to ignore duplicate inserts?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30499/optimal-way-to-ignore-duplicate-inserts)

I get the following error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 2:         INSERT INTO db_table (tbl_column) VALUES ('test');
                ^
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO db_table (tbl_column) select 'test' where not exists (select 1 from db_table where tbl_column = 'test')`. Or wait for 9.5 and use `insert on conflict`. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109061/330315

Comment: Thanks. I did find the 9.5 feature, looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t1 (id) VALUES (6);
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    -- Ignore duplicate inserts.


END$$;
```

You can not use IF outside procedure code, but Your construction possible run like this

Comment: Thank you so much. This does exactly what I wanted, and made me find the following documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html